# Toggle between different density maps using HTML

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I've got two separate figures that use callbacks to filter spatial coordinates. The figures contain a scatter plot and a heat map. Is it possible to incorporate both within a single figure, but use either a `Dropdown` or `RadioItems` to select one or the other?

Eventually, the single figure would contain multiple maps to visualise spatial coordinates (scatter, heat map, hex bin, etc.).

```python
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
       'Cat': ['t','y','y','y','f','f','j','k','k','k','s','s','s','s'],
       'LAT': [5,6,4,5,4,7,8,9,5,6,18,17,15,16],
       'LON': [10,11,9,11,10,8,8,5,8,7,18,16,16,17],
       })

N = 30
data = pd.concat([data] * N, ignore_index=True)

data['Color'] = data['Cat'].map(dict(zip(data['Cat'].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[:len(data['Cat'].unique())])))

Color = data['Color'].unique()

Type_Category = data['Cat'].unique()
Type_cats = dict(zip(Type_Category, Color))


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

filtering = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label('Cats', style = {'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Checklist(
            id = 'Cats',
            options = [
                {'label': 't', 'value': 't'},
                {'label': 'y', 'value': 'y'},
                {'label': 'f', 'value': 'f'},
                {'label': 'j', 'value': 'j'},
                {'label': 'k', 'value': 'k'},
                {'label': 's', 'value': 's'},
            ],
            value = ['t', 'y', 'f', 'j', 'k', 's'],
        ),
    ], className = "two columns",
    )
])

app.layout = dbc.Container([

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(filtering)),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'scatter-chart')),
            ]),
        ]),
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'heatmap-chart')),
    ])
], fluid = True)


df = data

@app.callback(
    Output('scatter-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("Cats", "value")])

def scatter_chart(cats):

    dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]

    data = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame = dff,
                                   lat = 'LAT',
                                   lon = 'LON',
                                   color = 'Cat',
                                   color_discrete_map = Type_cats,
                                   zoom = 3,
                                   mapbox_style = 'carto-positron',
                                   )

    fig = go.Figure(data = data)

    return fig


@app.callback(
    Output('heatmap-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("Cats", "value")])

def heatmap_chart(cats):

    dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]

    # Creating 2-D grid of features
    [X, Y] = np.meshgrid(dff['LAT'], dff['LON'])

    Z = np.cos(X / 2) + np.sin(Y / 4)

    fig = go.Figure(data =
           go.Densitymapbox(lat = dff['LON'],
                            lon = dff['LAT'],
                            z = Z,
                            )
                    )

    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style = "carto-positron")

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8051)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you can use `html.Div` and return `dcc.Graph` inside it. Something as below:

```python
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
       'Cat': ['t','y','y','y','f','f','j','k','k','k','s','s','s','s'],
       'LAT': [5,6,4,5,4,7,8,9,5,6,18,17,15,16],
       'LON': [10,11,9,11,10,8,8,5,8,7,18,16,16,17],
       })

N = 30
data = pd.concat([data] * N, ignore_index=True)

data['Color'] = data['Cat'].map(dict(zip(data['Cat'].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[:len(data['Cat'].unique())])))

Color = data['Color'].unique()

Type_Category = data['Cat'].unique()
Type_cats = dict(zip(Type_Category, Color))


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

filtering = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label('Cats', style = {'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Checklist(
            id = 'Cats',
            options = [
                {'label': 't', 'value': 't'},
                {'label': 'y', 'value': 'y'},
                {'label': 'f', 'value': 'f'},
                {'label': 'j', 'value': 'j'},
                {'label': 'k', 'value': 'k'},
                {'label': 's', 'value': 's'},
            ],
            value = ['t', 'y', 'f', 'j', 'k', 's'],
        ),
    ],
    )
])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(filtering),
            html.Label('Type', style = {'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
            dcc.RadioItems(['Scatter', 'Heatmaps'], 'Scatter', inline=True,id='maps'),
        ],width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(id='chart')],width=10)
    ])
], fluid = True)

df = data

@app.callback(
    Output('chart', 'children'),
    [Input("Cats", "value"),
     Input("maps", "value")])

def scatter_chart(cats,maps):
    if maps == 'Scatter':
        dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]
        data = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame = dff,
                                 lat = 'LAT',
                                 lon = 'LON',
                                 color = 'Cat',
                                 color_discrete_map = Type_cats,
                                 zoom = 3,
                                 mapbox_style = 'carto-positron',
                                )

        fig = go.Figure(data = data)

    else:
        dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]
        # Creating 2-D grid of features
        [X, Y] = np.meshgrid(dff['LAT'], dff['LON'])

        Z = np.cos(X / 2) + np.sin(Y / 4)

        fig = go.Figure(data =
           go.Densitymapbox(lat = dff['LON'],
                            lon = dff['LAT'],
                            z = Z,
                            )
                    )

        fig.update_layout(mapbox_style = "carto-positron")
    return dcc.Graph(figure=fig)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port = 8051)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @hoa tran. Could I return a single figure only with the same functionality?

Comment: Hm, it is returning single figure based on inputs. I'm not sure fully understand about your question.